# $G$ topological group. $G=UD=DU$, $D$ dense, $U$ open set

Tags: topological-groups

Let $G$ a topological group, $U \neq \emptyset$ open subset of $G$, $D$ dense in $G$. Prove $G=DU=UD$.

**Attempt 1** Take $V=U \cap U^{-1}$. $V$ is open set. Let $x \in G$ then $xV$ is open and $D$ dense, so $xV \cap D \neq \emptyset$. Then exists $v \in V, d \in D$ such that $xv=d$ then $x=dv^{-1} \in DV^{-1} \subset DV \subset DU. $ But the problem is that $V$ empty because for all $y \in U$ is not necessarily $y \in U^{-1}$.

**Attempt 2**. If $e \in U$, $e$ is identity of group.
Then exists $V$ a neighborhood of $e$ such that $V=V^{-1} \subset U$. Let $x \in G$ then $xV$ is a neighborhood of $x$ then $xV \cap D \neq \emptyset$, then $xv=d$ for some $v \in V, d \in D$ then $x=dv^{-1} \in DV^{-1} \subset DV \subset DU.$ But just se know that $U \neq \emptyset$ but I don't know how is possible $e \in U$.

Comment: How on earth did you get that $V$ is empty?

Comment: For example if se have an interval when se calculate with inverse, the intersection is empty. So, if it is not emty, why is the reason that I have no clear.

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming that $U$ is a neighborhood of the identity: This is when one uses symmetrization.

Comment: It's my principal problem, I don't know how argument the identity is in $U$.

Comment: Hint: First consider $xD^{-1}$ and prove that it intersects $U$. There is no need to symmetrize.

Comment: The reason is because $xD^{-1}$ is dense un $G$.

Comment: Of course. Can you finish the proof now?

Comment: Yes, I can. Thank you.